# Question about E step in Em algorithm, a challenge part, any help please?

Tags: expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, copula

I am new to EM algorithm and copula. I was reading a paper in mixture pair-copula. The authors use $u=(u_r, u_s) = (u_r^t,u_s^t), (t= 1,...,T)$ to indictae to the vector of copula data. Then, they identify the E-step to be the colculation of the conditional of $Z_{it}$ (it is the indicator variable that define from where each observation point was drawn) as follows (please see the photo. I used photo to avoid mistakes)

[image]

An important part if someone can help, what does the author mean by saying: "Due to the fact that $logL_c()$ is linear in $z_{it}$, the compulation of conditional expectation of (19) given u on the (m+1)th iteration leads to thh calculation of the conditional expectation of $Z_{it}$: ... " then define the equaiton (21).

This is equation (19).

[image]

The title of the paper is : Mixture pair-copula construction", by "Gregor N.F. Weiß ⇑, Marcus Scheffer".

Also, Why did the authors used bold index in equation (20) and (21) for the $u=(u_r, u_s)$ and did not use the bold in equation (22). From my understanding, that because in equations (20) and (21) we prefer to the whole data since the expectation is for all the point. However, for equation (22) we now use the density where we define each point ( we take point by point to calculate the density). Is that correct? (where $c_i$ indicates the density of copula type).